# How to make a Semantic UI React grid full screen with different row heights?

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am trying to make a [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com) grid full screen with a particular layout.

[image]

In my component I have the following render method:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid celled>
        <Grid.Row stretched>
          <Grid.Column width={10}>
            <p>One</p>
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={6}>
            <p>Two</p>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>

        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Column width={10}>
            <p>Three</p>
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={3}>
            <p>Four</p>
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={3}>
            <p>Five</p>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
```

The widths of the columns are correct but the heights are not. This is what the above code gives me:

[image]

How do I stretch the top row to fit 70% of the screen and the bottom the remaining 30%? Or how can I set the top row to 600px and the bottom row the remainder of the screen? Either way would be ok with me.

I have tried giving the component an id and setting that id to 100% in the style.css but the height is unchanged.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think `stretched` does what you are trying to do. Read the docs on [Stretched](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid#grid-example-stretched) to see their example.

You can set the height of the grid to `100vh`, the height of the first row to `70%`, and the height of the second row to `30%`. [Here's a jsfiddle example I put together.](https://jsfiddle.net/pf9wk2x3/2/)

```js
render() {
  return (
    <Grid celled padded style={{height: '100vh'}}>
      <Grid.Row style={{height: '70%'}}>
        <Grid.Column width={10}>
          <p>One</p>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={6}>
          <p>Two</p>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>

      <Grid.Row style={{height: '30%'}}>
        <Grid.Column width={10}>
          <p>Three</p>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={3}>
          <p>Four</p>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={3}>
          <p>Five</p>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```